# call any model or helper in codeigniter routes file

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

Is there any way so I can use any helper function in my routes.php?. Whenever I try to make $CI = & get_instance (); It's always give me error CI_controller not found? If I try to load any model that time also give me some error? How can I do this

Comment: You cannot use that.routes.php executes before controller,model class load

Comment: why would you want that in routes.php? perhaps theres another way to achieve what you desire

Comment: Why would you need to do this? What are you trying to accomplish?